# Ternary operator: exception throwing and nesting

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, operator-precedence, throw

I am having trouble understanding operator grouping in C++ when writing complex logical checks. **Basically**, I'm just concerned if this code:

```
int getIndex(int i) throw(Exception) {
    return (i >= 0 && i < length) ? array[i] : throw IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

is same as this one:

```
int getIndex(int i) throw(Exception) {
    return i >= 0 && i < length ? array[i] : throw IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

**Also**, I am uncertain what are the limitations while nesting ternary operators, because I want to make something like this:

```
int getIndex(int i) throw(Exception) {
    return (i >= 0 && i < capacity) ? ((i < length) ? (array[i]) : (throw IndexOfEmptyFieldException(); ) : (throw IndexOutOfBoundsException(); ))
}
```

but (of course) I want it to work correctly and also be readable.

If you think that this is **bad example** of using the ternary operator, should I just use `if/else` or some other method and avoid constructions like this one in the future?

Comment: There are two problems with your usage of the ternary expression, the first and most obvious is the readability/maintainability aspect. The second is that both branches of the expression must return the same type, which your doesn't. In fact, one of your branches doesn't return at all.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It compiled, although I didn't try running it. Also, the catch block for this exception terminates the program.

Comment: how does the nested ternary add to readability? I would definitely prefer if/else when there is more than one condition

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The standard specifically allows putting a throw expression inside a conditional (ternary) operator, in which case the result has the type of the other branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`? :` has lower precedence than `&&`, so yes, your first two examples are equivalent.

As for your third example, I'd write that as

```
int getIndex(int i) throw(Exception) {
    return
        i < 0 || i >= capacity ? throw IndexOutOfBoundsException() :
        i >= length            ? throw IndexOfEmptyFieldException() :
        array[i]
    ;
}
```

I think "nested" conditional operators are fine as long as they're "serialized", i.e. they form what amounts to an if/elsif/else chain.

This particular case is debatable though, because only one branch actually returns a value. The other two just throw an exception, and that's usually nicer as a separate statement: Throwing an exception has no real value as an expression; it's used solely for its side effects.